# ManyToMany relation - how update attribute in pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship, laravel-5

I am now learning to work with pivot tables: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

I have `WeeklyRoutine` model. Each routine has several Activities. The assigned activities are attached in a pivot table `activity_routine`.

Relation defined in the `WeeklyRoutine` model:

```
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity', 'activity_routine', 'routine_id', 'activity_id')->withPivot('done_at')->withTimestamps();
}
```

it looks like this:

```
// activity_routine pivot table (relevant columns only)
| id | activity_id | routine_id  | done_at             |
| 34  | 1          | 4           | 2016-04-23 09:27:27 | // *1
| 35  | 2          | 4           | null                | // *2
```

*1 this activity is marked as done with the code below
*2 this activity is not yet done

### what I have:

I can update the `done_at` field in the pivot table, thus making it marked as DONE for the given week (a weeklyroutine_id = 4 in the above code

```
public function make_an_activity_complete($routineid, $activityid) {

    $date = new \DateTime;


    $object = Routine::find($routineid)->activities()->updateExistingPivot($activityid, array('done_at' => $date));


    return 'done!';
}
```

### what I need

I want to UN-DO an activity. When it is already done,  that is when the `done_at` is not `null` buc contains a date, make it `null`.

In other words I need to do the below switch of value, but the proper way:

```
$pivot = DB::table('activity_routine')->where('routine_id, $routineid)->where('activity_id, $activityid)->first();
if($pivot->done_at != null) {
    $new_val = new \DateTime;
} else {
    $new_val = null;
}
    $object = Routine::find($routineid)->activities()->updateExistingPivot($activityid, array('done_at' => $new_val));
```

How to do it? I have no clue!

Thx.

Comment: Shouldn't the if statement in your last example be `===` instead of `!=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems fine to me. I would probably do it like this.

```
$routine = Routine::find($routineid);
$activity = $routine->activities()->find($activityid);
$done_at = is_null($activity->pivot->done_at) ? new \DateTime : null;

$routine->activities()->updateExistingPivot($activityid, compact('done_at'));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can I ask deeper? We create here two variables `$routine` and `$activity`. Is there any way to do get the targetted activity. Sth like `$activity = Routine::find($routine_id)->whereActivities()->find($activityid);`?

Comment: `$activity` is the targeted activity. The only difference between that and what you get from `$activity = Activity::find($activityid);` is the `->pivot` info. Otherwise its just a normal Eloquent Model instance representing one row in the activities table. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Uh, not really. The same activity can be assigned to different `Routine`s, so I'd have to create another model, `ActivityRoutine`. Ok, it's not really important. Thank you!
May I direct your attention to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856090/counting-models-related-through-manytomany-only-if-a-pivot-attribute-null-lara