# Counting Models related through manyToMany only if a pivot attribute null - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5, relation

I am elaborating code acquired here
[ManyToMany relation - how update attribute in pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809209/manytomany-relation-how-update-attribute-in-pivot-table)

### what I want:

I want to get a collection of `Activities` related to any weekly `Routine`. The pivot table's atribute `done_at` tells me when any activity (task) was completed.

I can list and later `->count()` activities related to parent model in manyToMany relation:

```
public function activities()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity', 'activity_routine', 'routine_id', 'activity_id')->withPivot('done_at')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now I want to get a collection of activities, which are not yet done. They have a pivot attribute `done_at` set to `null`.

### my attempt:

I wish the below code worked. Unfortunately it doesn't. 
I get error `Illegal operator`. When in stead of `'!='` I put simply `'='`, the code works like a dream, but it gives me list of Activities already done.

Any hints?

```
public function activitiesOnlyDone()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity')->withPivot('done_at')->wherePivot('done_at','!=',null);
}
```

---

Additional hints:
[getting the value of an extra pivot table column laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566675/getting-the-value-of-an-extra-pivot-table-column-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this instance, you can replace the

```
->wherePivot('done_at','!=',null);
```

with a simple

```
->whereNull('done_at');
```

If there are `done_at` columns on the other tables you will have to do

```
->whereNull('activity_routine.done_at');
```

This works because the Relation class uses Laravel's query builder to construct the final database query. And any methods called on a relation that are not defined in the Relation class will be passed to the query builder (Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder) via a `__call()` method.

Comment: much to my sorprise it works. Thank you. 
I have also submitted a bug report to Laravel/Framework, as the `Illegal operator` error is sth that needs fixing. Thank you!